# How can you filter out values in a JSON array with JQuery?

Tags: arrays, json

I am trying to filter out sections from lessons.
For example: Show section 2, then lesson 2 and lesson 3 in that section.  I used alert() for simplicity.

Once a section is shown then only lessons show, then the next section shows and it's lessons.  I tried parsing the section as an integer to make sure that numbers match numbers in the if statement.  I am not sure what I am doing wrong?

https://jsfiddle.net/soljohnston777/tn8ac0yk/5/

```
var jsonData = '[{"section_id":"1","lesson_name":"Lesson 1"},{"section":"2","lesson_name":"Lesson 2"},{"section":"2","lesson_name":"Lesson 3"},{"section":"3","lesson_name":"Lesson 4"},{"section":"3","lesson_name":"Lesson 5"},{"section":"3","lesson_name":"Lesson 6"},{"section":"3","lesson_name":"Lesson 7"},{"section":"3","lesson_name":"Lesson 8"},{"section":"4","lesson_name":"Lesson 9"}]';
var obj = JSON.parse(jsonData);
var i = 0;
$.each(obj.children, function(index,value){
    if(parseInt(value.section) != i){ 
        alert(value.lesson_name)
    }
    if(parseInt(value.section) == i){
        alert(value.section)
        i++;
    }
});
```

Comment: filter out sections from lessons , what does that mean?

Comment: show a section, then all the lessons in that section.... then go to the next section.  The section numbers have duplicates. For simplicity I used alert()